# How does one set custom parameters on the WordDelimiter TokenFilter

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I want to use Azure Search using the .NET SDK in C#.  How do I create an analyzer that uses the WordDelimiter TokenFilter with the property `preserveOriginal` set to true?

The properties for an custom analyzer only seem to include TokenFilterNames

```
private static void CmdletIndex(ISearchServiceClient 
serviceClient)
{
  var definition = new Index
  {
    Name = "cmdlets",
    Fields = FieldBuilder.BuildForType<CmdletModel>(),
    Analyzers = new[]
    {
        new CustomAnalyzer
        {
            Name = "my_analyzer",
            Tokenizer = TokenizerName.Standard,
            TokenFilters = new[]
            {
                TokenFilterName.WordDelimiter
            }
        }
    }
  };

  serviceClient.Indexes.Create(definition);
}
```

How do I use create a **WordDelimiter** TokenFilter and set custom properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to define a token filter first that is based on `WordDelimiter`, and then reference that in your custom analyzer.

I don't have a sample handy, but based on the code in your question, here is how I think it would work (disclaimer: not tested; not sure it even compiles, but hopefully it gives you the general idea):

```cs
private static void CmdletIndex(ISearchServiceClient 
serviceClient)
{
  var definition = new Index
  {
    Name = "cmdlets",
    Fields = FieldBuilder.BuildForType<CmdletModel>(),
    Analyzers = new[]
    {
        new CustomAnalyzer
        {
            Name = "my_analyzer",
            Tokenizer = TokenizerName.Standard,
            TokenFilters = new[]
            {
                "my_word_delimiter_filter"
            }
        }
    },
    TokenFilters = new[]
    {
        new WordDelimiterTokenFilter()
        {
            Name = "my_word_delimiter_filter",
            PreserveOriginal = true
        }
    }
  };

  serviceClient.Indexes.Create(definition);
}
```

Also, please be aware that a brand new SDK for Azure Cognitive Search will be generally available very soon (July 2020). It is similar to `Microsoft.Azure.Search`, but not backward compatible. If you want to evaluate the preview and provide feedback, you can find it [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Search.Documents).